# dagger2 Multiple dex files with Factories

Tags: android, build, dex, dagger-2

I got an Android Library project, which has 3 *android modules*.

- Module A (com.lib.a)
- Module B (com.lib.b)
- Module C (com.lib.c)

The *C* android module is just a *toolbox* included in A and B, it contains, for example a class `com.lib.c.APIExceptionParser`, and both A and B needs that parser.

So the `build.gradle` of both A and B contains

```
compile project(':C')
```

The thing is, I have a *Dagger2 Module* (in C module already) made to provide the parser

`com.lib.c.WebModule`

```
@Module
public class WebModule {
    @Provides
    public ErrorParser<ApiException> provideErrorParser(ApiExceptionParser apiExceptionParser) {
        return apiExceptionParser;
}
```

This module is included in both A and B with their *Dagger2 components*

`com.lib.a.AComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AModule.class, WebModule.class})
public interface AComponent {
    void inject(SomeClass class);
}
```

`com.lib.b.BComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {BModule.class, WebModule.class})
public interface BComponent {
    void inject(SomeClass class);
}
```

Then, when I try to build the project, the build is broken because of:

```
:dexDebug
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/lib/c/ApiExceptionParser_Factory;
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

So the file `com.lib.c.ApiExceptionParser_Factory` is generated twice, in both *A* and *B*

Of course, if I build both *A* and *B* one by one, the build works. But when I include them in the final project, the error is still the same.